# Show device markers based search user Thingsboard?

Tags: thingsboard

I'm using Thingsboard version 3.4.1, I want to display markers on the maps Thingsboard widget based on user search Input. So when the user searches for the item device that appears on the maps, only the device that matches the user's search.

How do I display the map icon that the user is looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Filter` feature:

1. Create widget with HTML `input` field.
2. Every time when user types, you need to create/update `USER` attribute ([example](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/6429#issuecomment-1109430978)) to save search text in it.
3. Create [dashboard filter](https://engix-ltd.github.io/docs/user-guide/advanced-filters/) that will compare device name or label with search text (use `contain` or `not contains` comparison functions).
4. Add filter from step 3 to map widget.

Comment: And how to get all datasource in thingsboard. I mean when I get **ctx.datasources** 1st I get all that data, but after search my data only data search, how to get the all datascource even I searching?

Comment: To grab all needed data sources use [Alias](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/ui/aliases/#alias-types) feature. Once you created alias for your devices/assets, add it and filter to map widget.

Comment: How to get it, I mean for get datasource we could get with **ctx.dataSources** but for the  all data that not changes even if user searching?

Comment: I mean if there are any specific services or api to get all list devices in my dashboard? if you know I'm really thank you.

Comment: There is no such API. Datasource is related to widget not to dashboard. By the way discussion at the moment is out of scope. So if you create another question and provide more information why you need both all and filtered data sources, I will try to help you

Comment: If I can get the data source, all the data and the search data source, I can compare them so that when the user types a word, I can replace the array. Why do I need all the initial datasource.

Comment: I want update marker maps based search user, if user input the id/name device it's should showing only the searched data on the marker maps.